# Wagtail OpenCV with Python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

Looking at this page http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/images/feature_detection.html

What would be the equivalent to

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv python-numpy
```

for python3 I've found python3-numpy but can't seem to find a version of opencv for python3, I've ended removing that from our Dockerfile and installing opencv-python==3.4.0.12 in our requirements file. This seems to work but is this a non standard way to handle this or is this ok?

Thanks

Joss

Comment: pip3 install opencv-python or you can try apt-get install python3-opencv

Comment: I've tried apt-get install python3-opencv, didn't work. As I've said  
pip3 install opencv-python does work, but is this way ok? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python 'Unofficial OpenCV packages for Python.' ?

Comment: sure it's fine, pip is a command for python to install packages, suppose you have a pc without python2 installed and only python3 i would not need to use pip3 but you will able to use pip! the 3 in pip3 is used to differentiate the commands if you have multiple instances of python installed (that is python2 and python3)... So pip3 install opencv-python is totally fine!

Comment: ok, Thanks for that.

Comment: OpenCV provides only a very limited set of pre-built binaries. You'll have to compile OpenCV by yourself or use some of the pre-built binary packages (your Linux distribution packages or opencv-python in PyPi). These packages have been created by someone else than OpenCV core developers and maintainers and that's why they are "unofficial". Pip is the recommended way to install Python packages. Python packages which are installed via apt-get are almost always outdated.